# Add python+regex as a favorite tag to avoid questions from the complement sets?

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, bookmarks

Is it possible to add "python AND regex" as a favorite tag and have questions at the intersection of the two sets as favorites? Possibly this question should be tagged with `feature-request` instead of `support`. Thanks.

Comment: Not currently possible, no. It sounds like a reasonable feature request, though.